# Read a weird txt file as data in R

Tags: r, text, datareader

I'm trying to get R to read data from a txt file, but the file is not properly made, so it's giving me lots of errors.
Ideally, I'd like to be able to extract a dataframe to be able to work with from this, but I trully don't know how to.

The files are all in [this link](https://stats.oecd.org/DownloadFiles.aspx?DatasetCode=CRS1).
An example with any of them would work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is weird about it? Looks like it would work using `readr` with `oecd  <- read_delim("./CRS 2020 data.txt", delim = "|")`.

Comment: Didn't know about that function...
Thanks a lot!!